# Ciclic class use inside another class

Tags: c++, class

I have two classes inside one cpp file like this:

```
class A
{
private:
  int somethingPrivate;
  B *aReferenceToB;
public
  B returnSomeB()
  {
    aReferenceToB->someFunction();
    return *aReferenceToB;
  }
};

class B
{
private:
  A needed_Class_A_var;
public:
  void someFunction()
  {
    return;
  }
};
```

This ciclic use of these two classes, one inside another, generates all sort of errors like

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

How can I resolve this ciclic include problem without creating separate files for each class and using only one cpp file?

I have tried to add a `class B;` declaration before `class A` definition wich does not work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you access members of the `B` class (`aReferenceToB->someFunction()`), or even try to return the object of `B` (not the pointer to `B`) (`B returnSomeB`), you need to have a complete definition of `class B` first.

So, just extract the `returnSomeB` body out of the `class A` definition, and put it in place where the full definition of `B` is known.

```
class B;

class A
{
private:
  int somethingPrivate;
  B *aReferenceToB;
public:
  B returnSomeB();
};

class B
{
private:
  A needed_Class_A_var;
public:
  void someFunction()
  {
    return;
  }
};



B A::returnSomeB(){
    aReferenceToB->someFunction();
    return *aReferenceToB;
}
```

Please note that if you try to write something like this:

```
class B;

class A
{
private:
  int somethingPrivate;
  B *aReferenceToB;
public:
  B* returnSomeB() { return aReferenceToB; }
};
```

that would be valid, because you're only manipulating with the pointers here (in this case, you're not creating object of `B`, and you don't access any of `B`'s members), and the size of the pointer is known at the compile time, even without `class B` definition.